# removing code from an exe file with hex editor possible? (c++)

Tags: c++, hex, editor, copy-protection

so I was wondering if I could simply use some identification passages in my application to identify the origin of a copyright infringement (not yet implemented, just a thought). But then I figured, probably it's possible to simply cut the respective passages in my code or edit them to make identification impossible with the help of a hex editor or thelike. Is this possible? Let's assume for example I would put a hidden comment into the code which could be accessed in a certain secret way (e.g. by clicking somewhere). Now if someone possessed two program units (i.e. which were sold to two different people) would he be able to delete/edit the ''difference'' in a hex editor?

Comment: It's usually possible, unless you encrypt and do all kinds of things that bloat the program with extra code and don't make the program better. There are people who go to great length to protect their code, though.

Comment: Any validation you can do on the user site can be circumvented by in ingenious user. Have you considered turning your app into a web app ?

Comment: yes, I thought about that, too but so far I only want to be able to identify the origin of a copyright infringement as this seems to mean the least effort and afaik every application gets hacked sooner or later anyway ...

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate a hash of (the important parts of) the executable, sign it cryptographically, and embed the hash and signature in the executable.  If the executable is modified, the hash will change.  If the hash is modified, the signature won't match.

If you'd prefer to prevent infringement, rather than just detecting it, then each time the executable runs, it can validate the hash and the signature, refusing to run if they've been modified.

Comment: A rogue customer can always edit the program to remove the hash check.

Comment: True; security measures can always be defeated, given enough time, resources, and determination.  If the software is valuable enough that this is an actual concern, then DIY security measures are the wrong way to go in the first place.

Comment: It doesn't really matter how "professional" the protection is: since the program needs to run, it can also be cracked. The game industry is a perfect example for this: no matter how much money and effort they spend on piracy protection schemes, they still find their games on the internet a day or two after release...

Comment: sounds like a sophisticated method :) Yes, I'm only interested in detection (not protection), at least for now. Like Christian says I also have the impression that everything gets hacked sooner or later. So I don't want to spend too much time on protection methods but rather be able to identify the origin. The license agreement would contain a warning which informs the user about that. I was thinking in that direction, concealing the respective passage, making it not appear (via comparison) in the editor so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

To identify the source of an application you need to be able to uniquely identify the application.

This is usually done by providing each customer with a unique key that must be present for the application to run. On start-up the application checks the key is present and is valid.

You can prevent **simple** editing of the key by using cryptographic means of encoding the key. Thus modifying the key with a hex editor will not produce a new key but an invalid key. Just make the program refuse to run when there is an invalid key.

Comment: I understand. I only want to make identification possible, the program may still be executed by others without knowing any keys. The only question would be what is a secure way to make it impossible to identify the identification. Yes, encryption - sounds like the only reasonable way to do it. Maybe with some kind of complicated formula.

Comment: The key is just a file that sits in the same directory as the application.